# Blogger - How to make view count visible for each post

Tags: blogger, blogspot

Just wonder, is it anyway that I can have the view count for each post under Blogger's dashboard displayed on every post? Meant that I do not want to implement a new visitor count, but rather take the counter from dashboard and display it to each post, so that visitor can see the actual number.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no publicly available API which returns individual posts view counts in Blogger.

Blogger only provides the endpoint for fetching the overall view count (accessible via the Stats tab) for the blog via their API (Refer to https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/pageViews )